# JQuery Chrome Extension not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm having an issue with my contentscript. I cannot get Jquery to function no matter what! Perhaps you can help me figure out what it is?

I am trying to "catch" a value I write in a field and pass it on for processing after I click a button. I am recieving the "$ is not defined" error which probably means it cannot load JQuery.

Here is my manifest, my html and my code:

```
 {
"name": "Test 2017",
"manifest_version": 2,
"version": "0.1",
"description": "TestApp Jquery",
"browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
},
"background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery-3.2.1.min.js",
    "background.js"
    ]
},
"permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
],
"content_scripts": 
[
    {
        "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "js":["jquery-3.2.1.min.js",
        "contentscript.js"]
    }
]
}
```

Popup.html:

```
 <html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        body { min-width:250px; text-align: center; }
        #click-me { font-size: 20px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div>Input: <input id="input">
  <input id="click-me" type="button" value="Go!"/>
</body>
```

Popup.js

```
 function clickHandler(e) {
chrome.extension.sendMessage({directive: "popup-click"}, function(response) 
{
    this.close(); // close the popup when the background finishes processing 
request
});
}


 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
document.getElementById('click-me').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
 })
```

background.js

```
 chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    switch (request.directive) {
    case "popup-click":
        // execute the content script
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { // defaults to the current tab
            file: "contentscript.js", // script to inject into page and run in sandbox
            allFrames: true // This injects script into iframes in the page and doesn't work before 4.0.266.0.
        });
        sendResponse({}); // sending back empty response to sender
        break;
    default:
        // helps debug when request directive doesn't match
        alert("Unmatched request of '" + request + "' from script to 
 background.js from " + sender);
    }
}
);
```

Contentscript.js where I try to run Jquery:

```
 var abc =  $("#input").val();
 console.log(abc);
```

And then I get the error.

Any help here? Why can't my extension load JQuery? I have the scripts loaded in the right order and all.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your jquery should be in popup.js, if you want to manipulate the popup DOM. contentscript.js is used to manipulate the DOM of the website that is loaded, not the popup. In the same way, contentscript.js doesn't recognize the jquery because there is none loaded onto the DOM of the website. Set a jquery script tag in popup.html and move the contentscript content to popup.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use a content script for what you are trying to achieve. Content scripts are used to control the DOM of the website that is loaded in your browser. The button you are trying to manipulate is in your popup window and is controlled by popup.js, not contentscript.js. Simply move the jquery code to popup.js and it should work as expected.

> [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) are JavaScript files that run in the context of web pages. By using the standard Document Object Model (DOM), they can read details of the web pages the browser visits, or make changes to them.

Popup.html (nothing changed here, jquery script tag is present):

```
 <html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        body { min-width:250px; text-align: center; }
        #click-me { font-size: 20px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div>Input: <input id="input">
  <input id="click-me" type="button" value="Go!"/>
</body>
```

Popup.js:

```
     function clickHandler(e) {
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({directive: "popup-click"}, function(response) 
    {
        this.close(); // close the popup when the background finishes processing 
    request
    });
    }


     document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
     document.getElementById('click-me').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
     })    

    var abc =  $("#input").val();
    console.log(abc);
```

Comment: Ah, all right. But if I want to grab my value and put it inside the page (make a change) I would have to use a contentscript, right? How would I pass my value all the way down there?

Comment: Yes, correct. You'll need to send a message from popup.js to contentscript.js and include the variable you want to pass. This link should have everything you need: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging